# How do i convert series into date time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data frame below. I wish to combine the date and time columns and create another column that is a datetime object.

I keep getting  `ValueError: time data '13/06/2019 00:00:00.026250' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'`

What am i missing on the conversion?

```
Index  Date     Time               Seconds             Counts   Pressure    
    12  12/06/2019  17:04:33.403250     1560359073.403250   12927   68.1614794953802
    13  12/06/2019  17:04:33.434500     1560359073.434500   12927   68.1614794953802
    14  12/06/2019  17:04:33.465750     1560359073.465750   12927   68.1614794953802
    15  12/06/2019  17:04:33.497000     1560359073.497000   12927   68.1614794953802
    16  12/06/2019  17:04:33.528250     1560359073.528250   12927   68.1614794953802
```

the code shown below is what i am using to convert date and time to a datetime object

```
df['DT'] = df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']
df['DT2'] = df['DT'].apply(lambda x : datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'))
df.head()
```

Comment: You should change: `%m/%d` to `%d/%m`.

Comment: i changed it still gettin an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['DT2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'])
```

The inbuilt pandas function performs consistently compared to the one in datetime functions for dataframes

Comment: thanks just took forever thought it wasn't working. took about 5 minutes to run.

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez specify the format; it should speed up by nearly an order of magnitude.